# Neo4j APOC A* Via paths

Tags: c#, neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

I'm trying to use APOC A* for routing:

```
match(s:Station {Name: "A"}), (e:Station { Name: "B"})
CALL apoc.algo.aStar(s, e,'Road>' ,'Length','Lat','Lon') YIELD path, weight
RETURN path, weight LIMIT 1
```

How would I specify via any via points? Currently I have to split the full path into chunks A -> B, B -> C, C -> D and so on.

```
public class Station {

    public long Id {get;set;}

    public string Name {get;set;}

    public double Lat {get;set;}

    public double Lon {get;set;}

}

public class Road {

    public double Length {get;set;}

}
```

Thanks.